# Haskell: Removing duplicates tuples from a list?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to get from the before to after state. Is there a convenient Haskell function for removing duplicate tuples from a list? Or perhaps it is something a bit more complicated such as iterating through the entire list?

```
Before: the list of tuples, sorted by word, as in
   [(2,"a"), (1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"dd")]
After: the list of sorted tuples with exact duplicates removed, as in
   [(2,"a"), (1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"dd")]
```

Comment: remove duplicates from *sorted* lists in *O(n)* time with `map head . group`.

Comment: if you allow for `...(1,"b"),(2,"b"),(1,"b"),...` then we'd have to use ``map (head . nub) . groupBy ((==) `on` snd)``. Presumably the longest group will still be short so `nub` won't be such a problem. If not, there's always `Set` or `HashMap`. Still, breaking it up into groups first, in *O(n)*, can't hurt. -- Another possibility is to re-sort lexicographically (with a [stable sort](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort)) by `snd` major and `fst` minor, which should be near-linear; and then put it through the `map head . group`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for `Eq a => [a] -> [a]` on [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]), returns [`nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) function:

> The nub function removes duplicate elements from a list. In particular, it keeps only the first occurrence of each element. (The name nub means `essence'.)

As in the documentation the more general case is [`nubBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy).

That said, this is an `O(n^2)` algorithm and may not be very efficient. An alternative would be to use [`Data.Set.fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Set.html#v:fromList) if the values are an instance of `Ord` type-class, as in:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

nub' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nub' = Set.toList . Set.fromList
```

though this will *not* maintain the order of the original list.

A simple set style solution which *maintains the order* of the original list can be:

```
import Data.Set (Set, member, insert, empty)

nub' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nub' = reverse . fst . foldl loop ([], empty)
    where
    loop :: Ord a => ([a], Set a) -> a -> ([a], Set a)
    loop acc@(xs, obs) x
        | x `member` obs = acc
        | otherwise = (x:xs, x `insert` obs)
```

Comment: @shamu11, `nub` is very slow for lists that are not short. If the elements can be ordered, you can do much better.

Comment: Ah `reverse . foldl`!  This is definitely a `foldr` problem, nice and streamy.

Comment: @behzad.nouri, this is a case where `foldr` will be quite a lot more efficient than `foldl`, and may even complete successfully in cases that would run `foldl` out of memory.

Comment: @dfeuer please do some _benchmarks_ and show that the foldr version will be "a lot more efficient". note that haskell `nub` function keeps the **first** occurrence of each element. so should its alternative implementations.

Comment: See my answer. I've spent enough days benchmarking list code not to need to benchmark this particular exercise.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to define a version of `nub` for `Ord`, I recommend using

```
nub' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nub' xs = foldr go (`seq` []) xs empty
  where
    go x r obs
      | x `member` obs = r obs
      | otherwise = obs' `seq` x : r obs'
      where obs' = x `insert` obs
```

To see what this is doing, you can get rid of the `foldr`:

```
nub' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nub' xs = nub'' xs empty
  where
    nub'' [] obs = obs `seq` []
    nub'' (y : ys) obs
      | y `member` obs = nub'' ys obs
      | otherwise = obs' `seq` y : nub'' ys obs'
      where obs' = y `insert` obs
```

One key point about this implementation, as opposed to 
behzad.nouri's, is that it produces elements lazily, as they are consumed. This is generally much better for cache utilization and garbage collection, as well as using a constant factor less memory than the reversing algorithm.